# Hibernate Validator uses wrong Persistence Provider

Tags: jpa, weblogic, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

We use Oracle Weblogic Server 10.3.6. It contains at runtime OpenJPA and EclipseLink in the classpath. We activate JPA2 with the following line in the commEnv.cmd:

```
set PRE_CLASSPATH=BEA_HOME\modules\javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar;
%BEA_HOME%\modules\com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar
```

When we use Bean Validation with validator.validate() there is the following AbstractMethodError: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil;

It works, wenn we configure javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_1-0-2.jar instead of javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar, but we need 2.0. And obviously, the Validation Provider uses OpenJPA, but it should use Eclipselink.

At development time, we use Hibernate Validator. But which validation provider uses Weblogic and how can we the validation provider force to use Eclipselink as persistence Provider? What means the error message?

Comment: Why would a BeanValidation API implementation use ANY JPA implementation? What makes you say it does? Where is the stack trace that says it does? A JPA provider can use a BeanValidation API implementation ... i.e the other way around

Comment: When I call hibernate.ValidatorImpl.validate() it returns an error with the message: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.getProviderUtil()Ljavax/persistence/spi/ProviderUtil. That means, hibernate validator uses the persistence provider. Any idea?

Comment: POST THE STACK TRACE .... in your question!

Comment: Bean Validation uses the JPA Provider very well. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-425. And there is no stack trace.

Comment: User gets a Throwable and says there is "no stack trace". LOL. Calling e.printStackTrace() says you're wrong. All exceptions in Java have a stack trace. Oh well, you're loss as you don't want to understand the problem

Comment: @All: I've found the solution. Look below.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution: Weblogic has more than one persistence provider in classpath in some circumstances. In my case OpenJPA based on JPA1 and EclipseLink based on JPA2 (Favorite). Hibernate validator uses the logic from the Persistence-class from the indicated API-Package to get the persistence provider. That implementation call a method on that persistence provider, which is found first - and OpenJPA is found first in my case. When hibernate validator uses JPA1-API and call the method on OpenJPA based on JPA1, everything is going well. But when it uses the JPA2-API and call the method on the old OpenJPA, there is the AbstractMethodError, because the method is new since JPA2. To fix this, I had to add the eclipselink.jar to the pre-classpath. Then Eclipselink is always the first persistence provider which is found and everything is going well. API and implementation match.

```
set PRE_CLASSPATH=BEA_HOME\modules\javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar;
%BEA_HOME%\modules\com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar;
%BEA_HOME%\modules\org.eclipse.persistence_1.2.0.0_2-3.jar;
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA2 in Weblogic 10.3.6 is only as a patch, this can be applied manually or through Smart Update:

Details at:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13720/using_toplink.htm#EJBAD1311

It is a patch because WLS 11g is not EE6, but they wanted to provide JPA2